# Octave error: urlwrite: unable to open file when tyiing to download a file

Tags: url, download, octave

Version5.2.0 Octave: I cannot write or read a URL (for download). I use W10 and Edge.

```
`>> [f, success, message] = urlread('https://static.stooq.com/db/h/d_macro_txt.zip')
>> [f, success, message] = urlwrite('https://static.stooq.com/db/h/d_macro_txt.zip','d:\')
error: urlwrite: unable to open file`
```

The url exists and I can download it with Edge. How can I debug this?

Edit: The file do be downloaded is not already opened; I have also tried with urlread and this is OK to read; Then I can save the 'read-file-variable' to disk with the save command. This doesn't succeed with a .zip file: then I can also save it but I cannot unzip. So I think this is not a permissions problem. What can it be?
Edit2: I have tried to 'urlread' the zip to a string (in GUI in the .m file) and then Octave GUI hangs before I can save it. Have to go to task manager to restart Octave.

Comment: Are you asking how to unzip a zip file with octave?

Answer (score 0):

urlwrite expects a filename as the second parameter, not a directory/drive.

Try:

```
[f, success, message] = urlwrite('https://static.stooq.com/db/h/d_macro_txt.zip','d:\d_macro_txt.zip')
```